# Google Play Alpha App BM-PPH-01 Error

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that I am making and have uploaded to the Google Play through my console and would like some people to test it.
I have created a Google Group and also added a different account for myself but get the following error:

> BM-PPH-01

Has anyone else seen or know what this means?

Comment: We have the exact same issue. Alpha test version on an app with a price that appears one the Play Store through the link provided to the tester but unable to download it because of the same error as you have.

Comment: I actually talked to a google play support staff and they said they have never heard of this problem. I am currently emailing about this because I would like to get this tested as my app is near completion.

Comment: You're a step ahead of me because the link I found to contact play store support redirected me to the main help page. My only clue for this error, is that it's related to the billing process for testing a paid app because the error occurs while trying to retrieve the credit card info and the price of the app. I've tried beta testing 2 other apps for other developers and it worked but theirs was free app.

Comment: Also experiencing this issue. Has anyone had any luck either figuring it our or at least finding a way to file a bug report with the play store?

Comment: We promoted the app from Beta to Prod last thursday and users haven't had any problems buying and downloading the app. We then uploaded another higher version to beta test and the test account was able to download the app but only after being charged the transaction. I double checked that the version it downloaded was the beta version and not the prod version. I don't know if this is the intended behaviour (charging users to beta test?) or a bug.

Comment: I can confirm that Beta and Alpha users have to pay. And you can't make your app free because you can't switch it back to paid. And there aren't promo codes.

Comment: Google replied through email "We've recently made some changes that may have resolved the problem (referring to the "BM-PPH-01" problem I think). Please note that test account users make real purchase your published in-app items, but without any actual charges to the user accounts." I followed up by asking if the actual app price would be charged, google replied "Please note that it is without any actual charges to the user accounts." Unfortunately, I cannot test this further anytime soon so I cannot confirm any of this.

Comment: It would also be incredibly helpful if Google allowed app developers to be a part of the alpha/beta testing.  You can't buy your own app. This means you can't pull the app off the store.

Comment: @wbdev has your device been rooted?

Comment: Are you outside the US?  [This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2181359) seems to indicate that may be the problem...?

Comment: Also, did you check the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752887/play-store-beta-testing-doesnt-work)?  It describes some fuzzy requirements of the Beta Testing configuration pretty well.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after paying for an app and after that the download process didn't start.

My solution:
I visited the http://play.google.com/ website through my PC, searched for the app and selected the target device through the install-button.

Comment: Having the same problem, I followed the Google Play link. What I learned -- which was not displayed on my mobile device -- is that the app was not compatible with that device. That's got to be the suckiest, most uninformative error message for such a common use case that I've ever seen. And to top it off, I got a notification while writing this that the app was downloading. WTH?

Answer (score 2):

BM-PPH-01 error message is usually shown when there is an incompatibility between any of the three App,Google Pay, Device.

The incompatibility can be the device's location such as Google play features not available when device is in China . An app can be restricted for downloading in US only.

The following links might provide some insights about this problem and possible workarounds.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2181359

http://codekiem.com/2013/02/13/market-helper/

Answer (score 2):

I just now received the same error code [BM-PPH-01] when trying to push a paid app from the Play Store using my desktop web browser to my compatible mobile device.

As a workaround I was able to visit the Play store from my compatible mobile device - the app began downloading as soon as I opened the Play Store app.  I had planned to click the app's Install button from the Play Store app but didn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.
Change your main address in Google Wallet according to the country whose store your are trying to buy/download.

Ex: I was trying to download a film using the German store but my main Google wallet address was set to Portugl. I changed the address and now it works.